# if-check for all array values

Tags: php, html

I have a form in HTML and a code in PHP. The form contains a lot of different `<input>` things. And I want some text to output in a browser only if **all** the fields are not empty.

For example, for two fields called `name` and `age`, I would do the following:

```
if($_POST['name'] and $_POST['age']) { ... }
```

But here I have much more than two fields. What should I do?

Comment: how many fields you had?

Comment: You should read about `for` loops.

Comment: [**This could help**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3190482/1415724)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
$allSet = true;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(empty($value)){
        $allSet = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the method, but doesn't give the specific error message to what has been left blank. Also you should move this into a function + trim the value before verifying if it's empty

Comment: Sure, there is a lot that could be done. The goal is to point him in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this if all inputs sent are required :

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST)) != count($_POST)) {
    // at least one input is empty
}
```

See **[array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**

This function returns the same array, without the values that are `null`, `false`, `0` or empty string. So if there is less entries in the filtered array than in the original, this means that at least one input has not been filled.

**Edit :** And it **[works](http://codepad.org/CQHZnWMY)** !

Comment: I like the solution, it's pretty slick, but it's probably not something that is on the right level for the guy that asked the question.

Comment: @Dragony Yeah, I like to make it simple and short. Maybe that's not on the "right level" of the down voters neither ! Still, it could be useful for anyone understands it :)

Comment: Actually, this one is a lot more simple and doesn't need an array of POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function. You can append required fields `array('name', 'age', 'phone')`

```
function checkPost()
{
    if (!$_POST) return false;

    $fields = array('name', 'age');
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        if(!$_POST[$field])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if(checkPost()) { ... }
```

Comment: The structure seems a tad too complex for what it looks, the OPS Skill level

Comment: No complex. Just require push new fields to array.