# php check if any of 30 form fields is empty

Tags: php, forms

I have more than 30 fields in a form, and can't believe that I must write an array to check if any of them is `empty (like`[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190464/php-check-if-any-posted-vars-are-empty-form-all-fields-required)`)`

I need something like `js`

```
$_POST[].each function{
 if this is empty...
}
```

and hope that 'php' `as so glorified` language has something like this or similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3190482/1852787

Comment: you need this validation in php or js

Comment: if you need a JS method, you need to tag it as such, as you wrote *"I need something like js"* - So is it php or js? your post is unclear.

Comment: @lalithkumar in php as stated in post title

Comment: You really should keep the language bashing to a minimum until you have learned the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $post)
{
    if( !empty($post) )
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading`

Comment: `[]` just slip of mind, thanks @RiggsFolly for making it correct.